# IntelliJ autocomplete: lower case first letter during autocomplete

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to find a setting where if I want to do something like:

```
Private MyCreatedObject _myCreateObject = new MyCreatedObject();
```

I am hoping to find a way for IntelliJ to auto complete the field name, currently when I try to auto complete after "Private MyCreatedObject _" I get "_MyCreatedObject".

Is there a way for IntelliJ to lower case the first letter so the auto complete suggestion become "_myCreatedObject"?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is possible, as IJ will fall back to "append class name to the end" if you don't use the autocomplete feature right from the very beginning of your variable name. You could try making a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-template-variables.html) (look for `decapitalize`) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always using the _ prefix for field names, you can get correct completion behavior by going to Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation and specifying _ as "Name prefix" for "Field".